# background color with increasing opacity using less

Tags: html, css, sass, less

i need to change the background color of the all the children with a gradual increase of opacity. the number of child is dynamic and will be inserted or deleted asynchronously. is there any solution to achieve the same with css or less.

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.1);
}

ul li:nth-child(2){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.2);
}

ul li:nth-child(3){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.3);
}

ul li:nth-child(4){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.4);
}

ul li:nth-child(5){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your example only goes up to `:nth-child(5)` and an opacity value of `0.5`. What would you want that value to be for the, say, fourteenth child …? Do you need an equal distribution of opacity 0-1 over 1-x items, or what exactly? Does this need to be dynamic, i.e. divided in .1 steps for when there’s ten items, but .05 steps when there’s twenty …? Massively under-specified problem.

Comment: opacity here is just an example for the real problem.

there can be N numbers of list item.

if we do not take opacity to consideration and only want to change the background color like rgb(0,0,0), rgb(1,0,0), rgb(2,0,0)... then how to do it, without writing like nth-child(1)

Comment: when the word `dynamically` is used, typically it means that you cannot do it with just CSS. You would need javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Added these styles

```
ul li {
 box-shadow: 2px 2px white, 0px 2px white;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8));
}
```

Instead of coloring each li, give a background gradient to the ul and create a box effect with box-shadow.

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px white, 0px 2px white;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i can do the same for background. but there are additional styles that also i need to modify, like the color of the text will be darker in lighter background and lighter in darker background. so i need a mixin solution for it

Comment: also if you are using gradient to the ul that means the background of the li is not a solid color it is a gradient ( e.g background of A is a gradient not blue with 10% opacity )